# Can you span a single file share across multiple servers?

Tags: file-server

Let's say I have one large file server that has a company-wide share.  That file server constantly runs into space issues.  Now let's say I have a dozen or so random servers (print servers, web servers, etc) that have a ton of free space.  Is there a way to utilize that in the company-wide file share?  Like spanning the storage across different servers but making that transparent to the user?

I know the likely answer is going to be get more storage for the file server, but I just curious if this is conceptually possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this maybe [Distributed File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29
.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Probably DFS will do it on Windows.

Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29 .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use DFS for Windows or one of the variety of clustered/distributed file systems for Linux such as Lustre but you don't mention what OS you're using. Come back with more detail and we'll be able to help more.

Comment: Either/or.  I was just wondering if it's possible.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are lots of file systems that will support this across a range of platforms, the term you're looking for is Distributed file system (DFS).

Since you don't specify any system in particular I'll give you the link to the Wikipedia article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_file_system and let you decide which fits, or post another question later.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - I got schooled. I never knew that you could do one without the other. Please ignore answer below. Leaving it up as an example of what not to do.

---

I believe that the answers referencing DFS won't help you. It will make a file share exist on multiple servers (and provide a single namespace for it as well), but it also replicates the entire contents to each server that hosts that share. I don't believe there's any way to partition it. It seems that you're asking (for example) if you can use 10 GB on your web server and 5 GB on your print server to make a 15 GB share. Using DFS, you would only have a 5 GB share on two servers.

If I'm misunderstanding your scenario, please edit your question to address these details.

Comment: You can do namespaces without replication.